# JQUERY - jQuery UI Nested Sortables 2 - help getting it working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm interested in using the following JQUERY - http://lucaswoj.com/2010/01/jquery-ui-nested-sortables-2/

However, I can't seem to get a demo instance of the plugin work.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#findit').nestedSortable({});
</script>




<div >
  <ul id="findit">
     <li>
        List Item Content
        <ul></ul>
     <li>
     <li>
        List Item Content 2
        <ul></ul>
     <li>
     <li>
        List Item Content 3
        <ul></ul>
     <li>
     <li>
        List Item Content 4
        <ul></ul>
     <li>

  <ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look at the jquery but you didn't close your unordered list properly

```
..
     <li>
        List Item Content 4
        <ul></ul>
     <li>

  **</ul>**
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Timmy. Just fixed that but it still isn't working. Are you able to get it to work on your end?